# CSS active class does not update on v-tab after Vuex mutation

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vuex

I am working on a application that has a v-tabs component with 2 v-tab.

The application is complex, so the active tab is stored in a Vuex store.

On the first tab, I have a button that when clicked, redirects me to the other tab. This is working fine.

The only thing is that the v-tab-active class does not update and stay on the first tab, even tough I am being redirected to the second tab correctly.

The v-tab-active class is updating well when I click directly on the tabs.

This is my tabs component :

```
<template>
    <v-tabs
        v-model="internalTabIndex"
        class="tabs-eval-secondary"
        height="48"
        color="blue_green_1"
        show-arrows
    >
        <v-tab v-for="(tab, index) in tabsLabels" :key="index" @click="updateEvalTab(tab)">
            {{ $t(tab) }}
        </v-tab>
    </v-tabs>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    name: "LayoutTabsEvalSecondary",
    props: {
        tabsLabels: {
            type: Array,
            default: () => ["tableau"],
        },
    },
    data: function () {
        return {
             * internalTabIndex: index de la tab active
             */
            internalTabIndex: null,
        };
    },
    computed: {
        currentTabLabel() {
            return this.$store.state.evaluationRE2020.navigation.currentTabLabelSecondary;
        },
    },
    watch: {
        tabsLabels: {
            immediate: true,
            handler: function (newValue) {
                this.internalTabIndex = newValue.indexOf(this.currentTabLabel);
                this.$store.commit(
                    "evaluationRE2020/navigation/setCurrentTabLabelSecondary",
                    newValue[this.internalTabIndex]
                );
            },
        },
    },
    methods: {
        updateEvalTab(tabLabel) {    
            this.$store.commit("evaluationRE2020/navigation/setCurrentTabLabelSecondary", tabLabel);
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

This is the method updating the current tab :

```
applyUserChoiceSaisieAutomatique(dataFromCloseEvent) {
            if (dataFromCloseEvent["choixUtilisateur"] == "valider") {
                this.showDialogSaisieAutomatiqueChantier = false;
                this.applySaisieAutomatiqueChantier();
                // change the active tab to the second tab called "composants"
                this.$store.commit(
                    "evaluationRE2020/navigation/setCurrentTabLabelSecondary",
                    "composants" 
                );
            }
        },
```

For now, the only solution I found is to update the class with a querySelector inside the method :

```
document
                .querySelector(".tabs-eval-secondary .v-tab--active")
                .classList.remove("v-tab--active");
            document
                .querySelector(`.tabs-eval-secondary .v-tab:last-child`)
                .classList.add("v-tab--active");
```

Comment: `v-tabs` uses `internalTabIndex` as model, but there are no more references in your code to this prop. Could you post the code where vuex changes `internalTabIndex`?

Comment: Hey! thanks for the comment! I've updated my code ;)